# Red Line when using tsx with next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

[image: Red line when using TSX with Next.js]

I don't know what a problem when I using TSX in React with TypeScript.
The red line appears.
Project runs successfully.
Why this red line appear and classes name in TSX not working?

```
  return <>

    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <div >
          <div>
            <Sidebar/>
          </div>
          <div>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where the "redline" that you mean? can you show more code or the screenshoot

Comment: i think you forgot to surrounding with a parentheses `return (
 <>
....
</>
)`

Comment: I'm Searched and I Found the problem solved.
Restart Visual Studio Solve the problem.
Thank You For your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does it say when you hover over one of the html tags? This line indicate some kind of error (which do not have to be an error in "the app wouldn't run" way), it can be just not ideally configured ide/file type/eslint/typescript or whatever. When you hover over the part with the error, it will tell you what is the problem and what is reporting it.

edit:

you have

```
return 
   <>...</>
```

but it should be

```
return (
   <> ... </>
)
```

Comment: I'm Searched and I Found the problem solved. Restart Visual Studio Solve the problem. Thank You For your answer.

Comment: nice, sometimes turns it off and on really help! :D